# Message on tv screen I want to get rid of

Tags: tv

When I play a film from my computer this sign comes up on my screen:

> would you like to reduce mouse pointer lag on tv using game low
> latency? Yes or no

How do I get rid of this message?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.thegamer.com/reduce-input-lag-tv-guide/ but TVs and game consoles are off-topic here.

Comment: You'll want to look through your TV settings, or read the manual, to see how to disable this.